# HTACCESS rewrite issue from index.php to index.html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite from 
http://localhost/htaccess-test/index.php TO 
http://localhost/htaccess-test/index.html on my localhost

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.html [NC,R,L] -> this not working
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.html?&%{QUERY_STRING} -> this is working fine
```

Why the first rewriterule is not working but second one is working fine

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.html [NC,R,L] ` should work fine